# De-serializing objects with serialized member classes

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

I have the following class:

```
[Serializable]
public class A : ISerializable
{

List<B> listOfBs = new List<B>();

public A()
      {
      // Create a bunch of B's and add them to listOfBs
      }

public A(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
      {
      listOfBs = (List<B>)info.GetValue("listOfBs",typeof(List<B>))
      listOfBs.Remove(x=>x.s==5)
      }

}
```

and

```
[Serializable]
public class B : ISerializable
{
    public int s;
    public B(int t)
        {
             s=t;
            }

    public B(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        {
        s = info.GetInt32("s");
        }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        {
        info.AddValue("s",s);
        }
}
```

The problem the `line listOfBs.Remove(x=>x.s==5)` throws an exception because B's de-serialization constructor doesn't run until A's is done.
When I step through the code, A's listOfBs is just an entry of NULL objects matching how many B's are actually in listOfBs

How does one solve this de-serialization sequence issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement [IDeserializationCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ideserializationcallback.aspx).  `IDeserializationCallback.OnDeserialization` is called when deserialization is complete for the whole object graph.

I believe class A would be the best place to implement it, and you would put your problem code in `A.OnDeserialization` as follows.

```
[Serializable]
public class A : ISerializable, IDeserializationCallback
{
  List<B> listOfBs = new List<B>();
  public A()
  {
  // Create a bunch of B's and add them to listOfBs
  }

  public void OnDeserialization()
  {
    listOfBs.Remove(x=>x.s==5)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm. I regret having but one upvote to give